# Copy rows of an excel table, excluding header when number of rows varies

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy contents of a table to another workbook, The number of rows varies but number of column headers is always the same, A:EX. Header in row 1, first row of data i want to copy is always row 2. but the number of populated rows will vary. I have tried to do this by simply using record macro, but it doesn't work due to the variable number of populated rows. I also tried to adopt the following SQL which finds last empty row and used it to copy from A2 to last empty row in column EX but it doesn't do anything. any help would be appreciated.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:EX" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "EX").End(xlUp).Row)

    
With ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "EX").End.Offset(-1)
    .Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value 'copy values
End With
```

Comment: Are there any empty rows?

Comment: I should have been clear about that sorry. No, there will be no empty rows between populated rows.

Comment: What is the name of the other (destination) workbook and its worksheet? At the moment you are trying to copy to the same worksheet. Do you maybe want to copy to the right of the data as a test? Please clarify.

Comment: I think i just need to know how to copy from A2 to last populated cell in column in EX. I have a macro running just now, but it assumed more than 1 row. So when used "Record Macro" I selected cell EX2 than ctrl+sft and down arrow, then ctrl+sft+left arrow copied and  pasted where  i need it. But when only one row populated, the above meant i copied all the null rows to last possible row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reference the Data of a 'Table' Range

- It is assumed that the 'table' range starts in `A1`, has one row of headers, and has no empty rows or columns.

```vb
Sub ReferenceTableData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rng As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found in table """ & .Address(0, 0) _
                & """ on sheet """ & ws.Name & """!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set rng = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
 
    MsgBox "You have referenced the range """ & rng.Address(0, 0) _
        & """ on sheet """ & ws.Name & """.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

- If you are sure that there is data, you can get away with the following (not recommended):

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rng As Range
With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
End With
```

- If your data is adjacent and starts in a different cell, you can use my `RefCurrentRegion` function. I have posted it already too many times in some of [my other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a9814069%20refcurrentregion%20created%3a2022&searchOn=3).

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated, I'll give that a try and let you know how i get on.

Answer (score 1):

- An option to dynamically locate the rows and cols
- Assumes the col A is populated in the table

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim  rng As Range, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastRow > 1 Then ' at least a data row
            Set rng = .Range("A2", .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
            ' your code
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```